# windows hobocopy ignorepattern choose folderA OR folderB - regex use | in command line

Tags: command-line-arguments

I am trying to use hobocopy to do a copy from X to Y.  I do not want a couple of the folders to come across so I thought the /ignorepattern param would be fine to use.  It works fine like so:

```
HoboCopy.exe /full /statefile=C:\scripts\test.dat /y /r C:\GIT\Apache \\192.168.0.2\backups\websites\testcopy /ignorepattern=repositories
```

In this case it will not copy the "repositories" folder.  But if I want to ignore two or more folders I need to use a regex (as I understand it) to skip them:

```
HoboCopy.exe /full /statefile=C:\scripts\test.dat /y /r C:\GIT\Apache \\192.168.0.2\backups\websites\testcopy /ignorepattern=repositories|temp-repo
```

The problem is it thinks the "|" is not part of the regex and I get the following error:

```
'temp-repo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

If I quote the regex pattern then it just copies all the folders across.

I am using hobocopy because it is good for shadow copies and I do not want various copying programs on the machine if I can just use the one across all tasks.

Thanks

Comment: didn't find a solution to this.  found very little online about it.  Ended up using hobocopy to take to a temp folder to ensure locks are ok. Then robocopy to do the correct copy.

Answer (score 0):

The shell escape character in Windows is ^. So you could try something like this:

```
HoboCopy.exe /ignorepattern=repositories^|temp-repo /full /statefile=C:\scripts\test.dat /y /r C:\GIT\Apache \\192.168.0.2\backups\websites\testcopy
```